# Smarter than If Else

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm trying to do a switch (of sorts) of commands.

```
if 'Who' in line.split()[:3]:
    Who(line)   
elif 'Where' in line.split()[:3]:
    Where(line)
elif 'What' in line.split()[:3]:
    What(line)
elif 'When' in line.split()[:3]:
    When(line)
elif 'How' in line.split()[:3]:
    How(line)
elif "Make" in line.split()[:3]:
    Make(line)
elif "Can You" in line.split()[:3]:
    CY(line)
else:
    print("OK")
```

So the explanation. If `Who`, `What`, etc. are in the first 3 words of the command then it executes the corresponding function. I just want to know if there is a smarter way to do this other than a lot of `if`,`elif` and `else`?

Comment: `case` or `switch`, whichever one is supported in python

Comment: @TheBrofessor: er, neither are supported.

Comment: "Can You" will never be in `line.split()[:3]`, so if you need to branch on multi-word commands you'll need to work a bit harder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try creating a dictionary with keys being the command names and the values the actual command functions. Example:

```
def who():
    ...

def where():
    ...

def default_command():
    ...

commands = {
    'who': who,
    'where': where,
    ...
}

# usage
cmd_name = line.split()[:3][0]  # or use all commands in the list
command_function = commands.get(cmd_name, default_command)
command_function()  # execute command
```

Comment: Your `cmd_name` is a list of strings, though, and so we can't use it to index into a dictionary.

Comment: This is perfect. Except for what @DSM said this works. I googled something similar to this but I couldn't wrap my brain around applying it, Thank you for the help

Comment: In Perl, this is called a Dispatch Table.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different approach: use command dispatch from the `cmd` library module:

```
import cmd

class CommandDispatch(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt = '> '

    def do_who(self, arguments):
        """
        This is the help text for who
        """
        print 'who is called with argument "{}"'.format(arguments)

    def do_quit(self, s):
        """ Quit the command loop """
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmd = CommandDispatch()
    cmd.cmdloop('Type help for a list of valid commands')
    print('Bye')
```

The program above will start a command loop with the prompt `'> '`. It provides 3 commands: `help` (provided by `cmd.Cmd`), `who` and `quit`. Here is a sample interaction:

```
$ python command_dispatch.py 
Type help for a list of valid commands
> help

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
help  quit  who

> help who

        This is the help text for who

> who am I?
who is called with argument "am I?"
> who
who is called with argument ""
> quit
Bye
```

Notes:

- The docstring for your command will also act as the help text
- `cmd.Cmd` takes care of all the dispatching details so you can concentrate on implementing your command
- If want to provide a command called `why`, then create a method named `do_why` and that command will be available.
- Please see the documentation for more information.

Comment: Ok this answers pretty much all of my questions. Thank you!